return data by column *label* depending on value from another column
New to Pandas, and am having great difficulty finding an answer to this question.
Given the following DataFrame:



category
foo_count
bar_count
bat_count




foo
10
20
30


bar
10
20
30


bat
10
20
30



I would like to generate a new column with only values where the category value matches the column name so that the final DataFrame would look like this:



category
count




foo
10


bar
20


bat
30



I feel like the answer to this is probably very simple and entails the map function along with reindexing in some form, but for the life of me I simply can't make it work.   Your help would be most appreciated because I'm not sure what to do next!
EDIT
Thank you all for the responses.  My problem is solved, but in the hopes for finding the most general answer for others (and to respond to the general curiosity) I'll try to explain in further detail what the issue is.
I am importing data from a source with the following data structure:



area
category
total
name
address
phone




1001

578
John Smith
123 Main
800.555.1212


1001

578
Jack White
321 South
310.555.1212


1002

99
Jane Fish
1938 Birch
714.555.1212


1002

99
Sue Black
1303 Foxplace
805.555.1212



The basic uniqueness is the combination of area and category, which produces a total integer (and other columns with other descriptive data that I need to keep, but are otherwise irrelevant to the problem.)  Most of the time, the category is blank, so the area serves as the unique identifier and handling this is straightforward.  But when the category is not blank, the data provider copies the relevant totals into new columns, corresponding to the category name.  For example:



area
category
One Total
Two Total
name
address
phone




1001
One
887
34
Sam Wise
data
data


1001
One
887
34
Iago Bird
data
data


1001
Two
887
34
Will Biker
data
data


1001
Two
887
34
Deanna Tray
data
data


1002
One
986
28
Sam Wise
data
data


1002
One
986
28
Iago Bird
data
data


1002
Two
986
28
Will Biker
data
data


1002
Two
986
28
Deanna Tray
data
data



So what I'm trying to do is consolidate those exploded columns into one total column that represents the relevant total according to the row's category.
This normalizes the two input formats into one, and allows me to load everything under the same schema.  So the resulting file would look like the following:



area
category
total
name
address
phone




1001
One
887
Sam Wise
data
data


1001
One
887
Iago Bird
data
data


1001
Two
34
Will Biker
data
data


1001
Two
34
Deanna Tray
data
data


1002
One
986
Sam Wise
data
data


1002
One
986
Iago Bird
data
data


1002
Two
28
Will Biker
data
data


1002
Two
28
Deanna Tray
data
data



So far I'm guaranteed the data source follows a key:value pair in terms of category: column, for example:
map = {
    'One': 'One Total',
    'Two': 'Two Total',
} 

But again, I've struggled with how to apply that map to get the resulting coalesced columns.
Thank you again for all the thoughtful answers!  I'll give this a day or two and then select and answer that best serves the general population.

This used to be simple (using the lookup method, which has since been deprecated). You now need to use indexing lookup.

Wild guess
Why not to take the first record and join it to the 'category' column, if numeric data for all rows are the same?
suffix = '_count'
count = (
    df
    .filter(like=suffix)    # or [[c for c in df.columns if c.endswith(suffix)]]
    .rename(columns=lambda name: name[:-len(suffix)])
    .iloc[0]                # get a record as a sequence with categories as its index
    .rename('count')        
)

result = df[['category']].join(count, on='category')    # LEFT JOIN by default
# or, if the original index is not important:
result = count.reindex(df['category']).reset_index()

Note, the way with mapping suggested by @mozway IMO is better in this case.
General case
In general case, we can aggregate data along the rows by selecting corresponding column values:
df['total'] = df.agg(lambda r: r[r['category']+'_count'], axis='columns')


Code to experiment with:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'area': [1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002],
    'category': ['One', 'One', 'Two', 'Two', 'One', 'One', 'Two', 'Two'],
    'One Total': [887, 887, 887, 887, 986, 986, 986, 986],
    'Two Total': [34, 34, 34, 34, 28, 28, 28, 28],
    'name': ['Sam Wise', 'Iago Bird', 'Will Biker', 'Deanna Tray', 'Sam Wise', 'Iago Bird', 'Will Biker', 'Deanna Tray'],
    'address': ['123 Main', '456 Main', '321 South', '123 South', '98 Birch', '76 Birch', '303 Foxplace', '101 Foxplace'],
    'phone': ['480.536.746', '899.165.939', '577.421.704', '613.328.389', '746.634.553', '403.783.452', '395.900.337', '304.742.660']
})

total_suffix = ' Total'
total_val = df.agg(lambda r: r[r['category']+total_suffix], axis=1)
total_loc = 1 + df.columns.get_loc('category')
df.insert(total_loc, 'total', total_val)
df.drop(columns=[x for x in df.columns if x.endswith(total_suffix)], inplace=True)
print(df)

Output:
   area category  total         name       address        phone
0  1001      One    887     Sam Wise      123 Main  480.536.746
1  1001      One    887    Iago Bird      456 Main  899.165.939
2  1001      Two     34   Will Biker     321 South  577.421.704
3  1001      Two     34  Deanna Tray     123 South  613.328.389
4  1002      One    986     Sam Wise      98 Birch  746.634.553
5  1002      One    986    Iago Bird      76 Birch  403.783.452
6  1002      Two     28   Will Biker  303 Foxplace  395.900.337
7  1002      Two     28  Deanna Tray  101 Foxplace  304.742.660


The logic is most likely incorrect. Assuming df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['foo', 'bar', 'bat'], 'foo_count': [10, 40, 70], 'bar_count': [20, 50, 80], 'bat_count': [30, 60, 90]})  as input I'd expect the output to be [10, 50, 90], not [10, 20, 30].

@mozway I can see your point. And I remember you once responded to a similar comment that you work with the data provided. So do I now. The data provided looks as if an error was made in its initial generation (the same numeric data in rows), and an attempt is being made to correct this. So in this case, if the categories and numeric columns are the same, we could basically take as an answer any record and cut off the suffix in the column names. I used joining to keep the original order and set of categories. That's my initial assumption based on experience. Of course, I could be wrong.

Fair enough, if the data in duplicated in all rows, then a map should work. I would do it this way though: df['count'] = df['category'].add('_count').map(df.iloc[0]) or df[['category']].assign(count=df['category'].add('_count').map(df.iloc[0])).

"The data provided looks as if an error was made in its initial generation (the same numeric data in rows), and an attempt is being made to correct this. "  Yes, this is exactly right.   That's the goal.
Given that you both think @mozway 's approach is correct it seems that should be pursued.  However, if you actually run that function on the sample dataset you get responses for area 1001 for all rows -- when it should change with the area.  Again, the unique combination is that of area and category.  I'm trying to find that number.

The canonical (and most efficient) approach would be to use indexing lookup, you just have to modify the input Series to append the "_count" suffix:
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['category']+'_count')

out = df[['category']].copy()

out['count'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]

Variant:
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['category']+'_count')
out = pd.DataFrame({'category': df['category'],
                    'count': df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx],
                   })

Another approach using melt (not as efficient and would remove rows without a match):
out = (df.melt('category', value_name='count',
              ignore_index=False)
         .loc[lambda x: x['category']+'_count' == x.pop('variable')]
       )

Output:
  category  count
0      foo     10
1      bar     20
2      bat     30

alternative understanding
If all values are identical within a given _count column, then a simpler approach would be:
out = df[['category']].assign(count=df['category'].add('_count').map(df.iloc[0]))


Can I suggest df.reindex(df['category']+'_count', axis=1).values.diagonal() for the first part? Not sure if pd.factorize is really needed.

@Vitalizzare that would work but if you have many rows with several duplicated categories that would create a much larger intermediate. Imagine 1000 times "foo", the indexing lookup approach would create a (1000, 1) intermediate, the diagonal approach a (1000, 1000) intermediate ;)

The only intermediate copy I can see here is ... reindex(cols, axis=1) ..., which seems to be a square array of size len(df) anyway. Could you say, please, where I'm wrong?

@Vitalizzare it's not wrong, it's just not as efficient in the best case. Assuming n rows with k unique categories (k <= n) then your approach always has an intermediate with n² values while indexing lookup will be n*k which is really equal to n² in the worst case, but potentially much less if there are duplicated categories.

I'm not sure i've got you right.
But for example, if you want to take the row count in which the column is that count_name you can apply a function to create a column.
# Function to apply to each row
def extract_count(row):
    category = row['category']
    count_col = f"{category}_count"
    return row.get(count_col, None)

# Applying the function and creating the new 'count' column
df['count'] = df.apply(extract_count, axis=1)

The function is applied on axis=1, and gets the name of the column depending on the category name.
Then to construct the new data with the two columns:
# Resulting DataFrame
df = df[['category', 'count']]


For Huge datasets, USE : pd.factorize
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'area': [1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002],
    'category': ['One', 'One', 'Two', 'Two', 'One', 'One', 'Two', 'Two'],
    'One Total': [887, 887, 887, 887, 986, 986, 986, 986],
    'Two Total': [34, 34, 34, 34, 28, 28, 28, 28],
    'name': ['Gina', 'Sova', 'Roopa', 'Maela', 'Tabu', 'Soudipta', 'Protijayi', 'Tania'],
    'address': ['data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data'],
    'phone': ['data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
"""
  area category  One Total  Two Total       name address phone
0  1001      One        887         34       Gina    data  data
1  1001      One        887         34       Sova    data  data
2  1001      Two        887         34      Roopa    data  data
3  1001      Two        887         34      Maela    data  data
4  1002      One        986         28       Tabu    data  data
5  1002      One        986         28   Soudipta    data  data
6  1002      Two        986         28  Protijayi    data  data
7  1002      Two        986         28      Tania    data  data
"""


category_codes,category_unique = pd.factorize(df['category'])
print(category_unique)#Index(['One', 'Two'], dtype='object')

category_to_total = dict(zip(df['category'].unique(), df.columns[2:4]))

print(category_to_total)#{'One': 'One Total', 'Two': 'Two Total'}

df['total'] =[ df.at[i , category_to_total[cat] ] for i,cat in enumerate(df['category'])]
print(df)
"""
  area category  One Total  Two Total       name address phone  total
0  1001      One        887         34       Gina    data  data    887
1  1001      One        887         34       Sova    data  data    887
2  1001      Two        887         34      Roopa    data  data     34
3  1001      Two        887         34      Maela    data  data     34
4  1002      One        986         28       Tabu    data  data    986
5  1002      One        986         28   Soudipta    data  data    986
6  1002      Two        986         28  Protijayi    data  data     28
7  1002      Two        986         28      Tania    data  data     28
"""
res= df.drop(columns = df.columns[2:4])
print(res)
"""
  area category       name address phone  total
0  1001      One       Gina    data  data    887
1  1001      One       Sova    data  data    887
2  1001      Two      Roopa    data  data     34
3  1001      Two      Maela    data  data     34
4  1002      One       Tabu    data  data    986
5  1002      One   Soudipta    data  data    986
6  1002      Two  Protijayi    data  data     28
7  1002      Two      Tania    data  data     28
"""

